# MySQL syntax query for checking multiple values at once

Tags: mysql, database

How do I make this work in MySQL

```
select (3,5) not in (5,9,8);
```

where it should return 0 because 5 is in (5,9,8).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a table? Or is this question about this query?

Comment: I do have a table where I want to check if any value in one column is present in another column of another table.

Comment: Then share the table with example data and expected output.. then you get much better help.

Comment: What reference to select syntax are you using and where are you stuck? Also you are not clear, please use more words and sentences. Also try translate.google.com which is lately much better via AI.

Answer (score 0):

To check if any value in "one column" is present in "another column" of "another table".

**Using EXISTS**

```
SELECT
      one_column
FROM one_table t1
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT NULL
      FROM another_table t2
      WHERE t1.one_column = t2.another_column
      )
;
```

Note in that example above, the subquery select clause does not need to return any values because "checking for existence" occurs in the where clause of that subquery. However a select clause is needed for correct syntax but really it is just decorative here (and so "select 1" or "select *" may be used instead of "select null").

**Using IN()**

```
SELECT
      one_column
FROM one_table
WHERE one_column IN (
      SELECT another_column
      FROM another_table
      )
;
```

The select clause in this subquery does have to return values for comparison. Be wary of NULLs being returned if using IN().